# Splitting a sentence into two and storing them into a defaultdict as key and value in Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, counter, split

I have some questions about Defaultdict and Counter. I have a situation where I have a text file with one sentence per line. I want to split up the sentence into two (at first space) and store them into a dictionary with the first substring as the key and the second substring as the value. The reason for doing this is so that I can get a total number of sentences that share the same key.

```
Text file format:
d1 This is an example
id3 Hello World
id1 This is also an example
id4 Hello Hello World
.
.
```

This is what I have tried but it doesn't work. I have looked at Counter but it's a bit tricky in my situation.

```
try:
    openFileObject = open('test.txt', "r")
    try:             

        with openFileObject as infile:
            for line in infile:

                #Break up line into two strings at first space                    
                tempLine = line.split(' ' , 1)

                classDict = defaultdict(tempLine)         
                for tempLine[0], tempLine[1] in tempLine: 
                    classDict[tempLine[0]].append(tempLine[1]) 

            #Get the total number of keys  
            len(classDict)

            #Get value for key id1 (should return 2) 

    finally:
        print 'Done.'
        openFileObject.close()
except IOError:
    pass
```

Is there a way to do this without splitting up the sentences and storing them as tuples in a huge list before attempting using Counter or defaultdict? Thanks!

EDIT: Thanks to all who answered. I finally found out where I went wrong in this. I edited the program with all the suggestions given by everyone.

```
openFileObject = open(filename, "r")           
tempList = []

with openFileObject as infile:
    for line in infile:

        tempLine = line.split(' ' , 1)
        tempList.append(tempLine) 

        classDict = defaultdict(list) #My error is here where I used tempLine instead if list
        for key, value in tempList: 
            classDict[key].append(value)   

            print len(classDict) 
            print len(classDict['key'])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `collections.Counter` to "get a total number of sentences that share the same key."

```
from collections import Counter
with openFileObject as infile:
    print Counter(x.split()[0] for x in infile)
```

will print

```
Counter({'id1': 2, 'id4': 1, 'id3': 1})
```

If you want to store a list of all the lines, your main mistake is here

```
classDict = defaultdict(tempLine)
```

For this pattern, you should be using

```
classDict = defaultdict(list)
```

But there's no point storing all those lines in a list if you're just indenting on taking the length.

Comment: Out of interest, do you think `x.split()[0]` would be slower than `x.split(' ', 1)[0]`?

Comment: @AleXL, I'd use `x.partition(' ')[0]` if I was concerned about performance

Comment: @gnibbler - out of curiousity, if I want to store all the strings, can that be done?

Comment: @Cryssie, yes. The easy way is to store them in a `defaultdict(list)` and `append` as you were trying to do in the question

Comment: @gnibbler - Thanks a lot! I failed to see that it should be list and not tempList. It took me a while to realise it.

Answer (score 1):

`dict.get(key, 0)` return current accumulated count. If key was not in dict, return 0.

```
classDict = {}

with open('text.txt') as infile:
    for line in infile:
        key = line.split(' ' , 1)[0]
        classDict[key] = classDict.get(key, 0) + 1

    print(len(classDict))
    for key in classDict:
        print('{}: {}'.format(key, classDict[key]))
```

http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get

Comment: Alternatively, you can use [defaultdict](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#defaultdict-objects) - `classDict = defaultdict(int)` then `classDict[key] += 1`

Comment: @AlexL, I didn't use defaultdict because OP's `before attempting using Counter or defaultdict` in the post. Maybe, I misunderstood.

Comment: No I think you're right - I misunderstood. I'll leave my answer as an alternative (Also apologies for editing your answer, I meant to edit mine!)

Answer (score 1):

Full example of defaultdict (and improved way of displaying classDict)

```
from collections import defaultdict

classDict = defaultdict(int)

with open('text.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        first_word = line.split()[0]
        classDict[first_word] += 1

    print(len(classDict))
    for key, value in classDict.iteritems():
        print('{}: {}'.format(key, value))
```